# Download Youtube subtitles without timer using pytube

Tags: python, pytube

I am using pytube to download subtitles of youtube video. I want to download them without time information. I have checked their API documentation but I am unable to find option to get subtitle without timer. Following is my code.

```
from pytube import YouTube
source = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Af6b_wyiwI')
en_caption = source.captions.get_by_language_code('en')
en_caption_convert_to_srt =(en_caption.generate_srt_captions())
print(en_caption_convert_to_srt)
```

Comment: If there's no option, are you open to figuring out how to strip out the time information yourself?

Comment: Yes i am thinking to perform some string operations, but just wondering if somebody has done this already

Answer (score 0):

I found ridiculous solution in bottom -https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1674. So when I add row `print(len(yt.streams))` before "captions" it start working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).